# Generate « and » characters from keyboard

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I'm trying to make it so I can press `ctrl + cmd + [` to create `«` and `ctrl + cmd + ]` to create `»`.

I tried searching google and couldn't find anything that would allow me to do this and all the tutorials seem to do things differently from what I'm trying to achieve.

I have tried https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/ but I can't figure out how to setup custom keypresses.

Comment: What keyboard language? On UK English those are already available using alt \ & alt shift \

Comment: Yeah an English keyboard... Ah I did not know that! I was looking for it but I wasn't sure. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I tightened the question title so it's easier for future searchers to google

Comment: that makes sense, hopefully it will be easier for someone else to find this out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On UK English, those characters are available on

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>\</kbd>    «
&
 <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>    <kbd>\</kbd>   »

The Keyboard Viewer is useful for finding some of the obscure ones, available from the menu bar after setting System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard to show there.